# Flute Case with no sections/partitions

Tags: flute, storage

My wife plays the flute so we had gotten her a Crossrock carbon fiber case for it without realizing that there are no partitions for the individual flute pieces. My wife loves the case but we can't figure out how to store her flute in it. All it has are 2 soft pieces that have velcro on them. Can someone explain to me how to safely store a flute in this kind of a case? All the cases I've ever seen have partitions.

Edit: Thanks for the help. Sorry that I forgot to include some images. The picture I took shows the inside of the case and the 2 padding pieces.

[image]

Here's another image with the flute pieces inside. It seems no matter where I put the flute pieces and the padding, the parts just keep hitting against each other.
[image]

Comment: Have a look on the Crossrock site - pic. of a double case with flute, showing how padding fits. Can't believe the price - scandalous! And really no safer than any of my £10 cases... (all of which have compartments!!!)

Comment: Is the case longer than the flute, at least?

Comment: @Dekkadeci - generally, flutes split into 3, 1/2, 1/4, 1/4 roughly, so any case will be around 1/2 the length.

Comment: We miss details. What kind of case it is, is it sold as a flute case? What kind of flute? Perhaps it's meant for another type of flute? The producer should provide answers to those questions. Perhaps you can still exchange the case with another, better suited for your flute?

Comment: @Tom I've edited the question to include an image of the interior of the case.

Comment: @Tim Honestly, I can't get the Crossrock website to show me anything but guitar cases. Everything else just comes up with a blank page. I'll try to look for that image again later. Perhaps there's just a problem with my connection.

Comment: I'm not a flautist, but I have used electronic equipment cases with a similar arrangement.  The two dividers (on the table next to the case in your photo) should attach with velcro to keep the disassembled flute joints from bumping eachother.  Are the two square blocks also held in with velcro?  If so, they could also be repositioned as needed.  Maybe you could also post a photo that includes the disassembled flute for scale.  That would help give a more specific answer.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious that the top run is for the flute body, and the two velcro bits separate the body from the lower main compartment and then within that compartment separate the head joint from the end section.   Would be nice if it had a way to constrain the swab-rod, though.

Comment: @Theodore - I just added a new image showing the flute pieces with the case. I can't figure out how the 2 padding strips help. No matter where I place the flute pieces or the strips the different sections of the flute bang together. Unfortunately the 2 square blocks are not velcro. It would be nice if they were.

Comment: Have you considered using the strips to *wrap around* the flute pieces? Are they too inflexible to do so?

Comment: Matthew, it certainly seems that everyone else has no problem with this case.  I can pretty much guarantee that you can place the pieces as I described previously, and that the strips's velcro tabs will stick to the large square pads.   For the body, if necessary, remove one or both of the tiny blocks at each end of the long cavity.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Could the swab rod get tucked between the square padding blocks and the hinge side of the case?

Comment: I'm thinking that this might be a flute case for bamboo flutes, not concert flutes... If possible, you should send it back, because the padding provided will not be enough to position the pieces in such a way that they don't "float around" while the flute is being carried, which is _bad_.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a large and several small foam pieces missing. See [video on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T891MQF)
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Edward added picture.

Comment: Uh, this looks bad! While such placement prevents the two parts from scratching each other, there is very little padding to protect them from impact when something hits the edge of the case!

Comment: To clarify, the answer is not wrong, as it identifies the product, and shows the producer solution, but that solution is not good, in my opinion.